# Tools for side-by-side localisation of iPhone App

Tags: objective-c, ios, excel, internationalization

I have an App that is translated to four languages. I find that updating and maintaining the `strings` files extremely tedious.

Is there a way to edit different translations side by side similar to what IntelliJ provides:

[image: intellij]
<sub>(source: [jetbrains.com](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/screenshots/resource_bundle_editor.gif))</sub>

I would also be happy with a simply MS-Excel to Strings conversion script, where the Excel would be the master and the `.strings` files would be generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These apps saved me from a world of hurt. There's no guide, so you'd have to figure it out yourself. The apps are free though and very well designed.

http://www.loc-suite.org/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about [Linguan](http://www.cocoanetics.com/apps/linguan/)?

Answer (score 0):

My company use a tool called [Localization Helper](http://itunes.apple.com/de/app/localization-helper/id424218369?mt=12) from Mac App Store. I reckon it's pretty good.